# I have a scoreboard that shows a player's health below their name. Is it possible to change the color of that?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Basically, what I'm trying to say is, if a player drops below a certain number of HP, can I make it so that the color of the HP display (below their name) changes color? I want to have it so as long as the player is above 25% of their HP, the display stays white, but if they drop below that, the display turns yellow (to indicate if someone is low).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe creating new scoreboard with other color that overplaces uncolored when player has low HP? Overplacing system can be made with

```
/team join [low hp team] @a[nbt={Health:..5}]
```

or something like that should work.

If `{Health}` NBT isn't working, try with ""